# How to create file with help of P/Invoke to read boot sector and display .MBR?

Tags: c#, mbr

I've browsed through the CreateFile documentation... still wondering how should I use P/Invoke to call CreateFile and to read the boot sector, to display out the .MBR?

Any reference code for this portion? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Baget's answer, you can call `CreateFile` like this:

```
hFile = CreateFile("\\\\.\\physicaldrive0", 
    GENERIC_READ | FILE_SHARE_READ,
    0,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    0);
```

Comment: Vote up, because of the example :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503/modifying-the-mbr-of-windows) will help you

Basically you need to access a device using this syntax in the filename `"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0"`