# How to call "CreateFile" in C#?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

After getting so much information about [retrieving .MBR from a storage device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412634/how-to-create-file-with-help-of-p-invoke-to-read-boot-sector-and-display-mbr), conclusion is to use P/Invoke to call `CreateFile`.

But how this can be done in C#? Please illustrate! Your help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 20):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, 
    SetLastError = true)]
public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    uint dwShareMode,
    IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
    uint dwCreationDisposition,
    uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile
);
```

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateFile.html