# How do I disassemble raw MIPS code?

Tags: linux, assembly, mips, objdump

Similarly to [How do I disassemble raw x86 code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1737095/427545), but then for the MIPS architecture: how do I disassemble raw MIPS code with `objdump`? I want to check the instructions in a vmlinux image, but to do so I now have to:

```
: > x.c
mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc -c -o x.o x.c
mipsel-linux-gnu-objcopy --add-section raw=vmlinux x.o
mipsel-linux-gnu-objcopy --remove-section .comment x.o
mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump -D x.o | less
```

Is there an easier way to do it? I've tried the below to no avail:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump -b elf32-tradlittlemips -mmips -Mgpr-names=O32,cp0-names=mips1,cp0-names=mips1,hwr-names=mips1,reg-names=mips1 -D vmlinux | less
```

It just spits out:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump: vmlinux: File format not recognized
```

If it helps, here is the output of some commands:

```
$ file x.o
x.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), with unknown capability 0xf41 = 0x756e6700, with unknown capability 0x70100 = 0x1040000, not stripped
$ mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump -p x.o

x.o:     file format elf32-tradlittlemips
private flags = 1006: [abi=O32] [mips1] [not 32bitmode] [PIC] [CPIC]
```

The target is an AR7 CPU.

Comment: If you don't insist on using objdump, see also [Mips disassembler - Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13656/mips-disassembler)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm, it seems easier than that. `-b elf32-tradlittlemips` does not work because the file is not an ELF executable, but binary. So, the correct option to be used is `-b binary`. The other option, `-mmips` makes objdump recognize the file as binary for MIPS. Since the target machine is little endian, I also had to add `-EL` to make the output match the output for `x.o`.

`-mmips` only includes the basic instruction set. The AR7 has a MIPS32 processor which [has more instructions](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Instruction_Set_Architecture#MIPS32) than just mips. To decode these newer MIPS32 instructions, use `-mmips:isa32`. A list of available ISAs can be listed with `objdump -i -m`.

The final command becomes:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump -b binary -mmips:isa32 -EL -D vmlinux
```

This would show registers like `$3` instead of their names. To adjust that, I used the next additional options which are mentioned in `mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump --help`:

```
-Mgpr-names=32,cp0-names=mips32,cp0-names=mips32,hwr-names=mips32,reg-names=mips32
```

I chose for `mips32` after reading:

- http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/AR7
- http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Instruction_Set_Architecture

Answer (score 0):

??? What's wrong with just:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc -c -o x.o x.c
mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump -D x.o
```

Is the problem that `-D` diassembles all the sections, code or not? Use `-d` then. Or `-S` to show assembly interleaved with source (implies `-d`).

or how about getting the assembly code from gcc:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc -S x.c
```

Comment: vmlinux does not contain any sections, it is contains instructions only. The problem is, I don't have the gcc and objcopy tools installed, only in a VM. Since there was a way to get objdump skip the gcc/objcopy path in x86, I was wondering if it's possible on mips as well?

Comment: I see; your object file `x.o` is just a dummy, and you're pulling in sections from `vmlinux`.  That's odd; I've always been able to just run `objdump` on `vmlinux`, for various architectures: MIPS, ARM, ...  What does that `mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump` spit out if you just call it with `-d vmlinux`, without those other arguments? Also: `file vmlinux`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ODA, the online disassembler:

http://www.onlinedisassembler.com

Comment: ODA limits file size to upload up to 256KB only. Also, its web interface isn't very intuitive, too.