# Diagnosing boot loader code in QEMU?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86-16, bootloader, real-mode

Diagnosing boot loader code in QEMU?

I am trying to create a minimal 'boot loader code' that print the character 'A' and then halt.

I wrote the following C++ program for the purpose

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  /*
   * If I run these code directly in Windows, it crashes, for I believe Windows 
   * do not allow accessing the BIOS directly, that make sense
   * 
   * But I can compile a binary, then I can use the debugger to view what machine code
   * does these correspond to, and build to boot program!
   */
  /*
  __asm
  {
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x41
    mov bx, 15
    int 0x10
    hlt
lp: jmp lp   
  }
   */
  int disk_length = 80 * 18 * 512 * 2;
  char* disk = (char*)calloc(disk_length, sizeof(char));

  const char program[] =
  {
    0xb4, 0x0e,             //     mov ah, 0EH
    0xb0, 0x41,             //     mov al, 41H
    0x66, 0xbb, 0x0f, 0x00, //     mov bx, 0FH
    0xcd, 0x10,             //     int 10H
    0xf4,                   //     hlt
    0xeb, 0xfe              // lp: jmp lp
  };
  const char boot_signature[] = {0x55, 0xAA};

  const int program_length = _countof(program);
  const int boot_signature_length = _countof(boot_signature);

  // Be careful with file mode
  FILE* imgFile = fopen("disk.img", "wb");

  memcpy(disk, program, program_length);
  memcpy(disk + 510, boot_signature, boot_signature_length);

  int written = 0;
  while (written < disk_length)
  {
    written += fwrite(disk + written, sizeof(char), disk_length - written, imgFile);
  }
  fclose(imgFile);

  return 0;
}
```

First, I ran the code with the inline assembly uncommented. In the debugger, I derived the opcodes and is certain the opcode matches the ones in my source code.
Next, I ran the code with the inline assembly commented, then I generated a img file. I used a binary editor to look at the content and make sure it looks the way I wanted it.
Last, I ran qemu-system-i386.exe -fda disk.img, I am expecting the boot loader program to show a capital 'A', but instead, nothing is shown.

Now I have two questions:

1.) What's wrong with my code? 
2.) How do I diagnose it?

Comment: I find it amusing that you ended up writing a program just to put bytes into a disk image.  On Linux you'd just use `dd` for this.  (Michael's answer is correct BTW: you compiled/assembled your code for 32bit mode, but are then running those instructions in 16bit mode.  So you have operand-size prefixes where there shouldn't be any.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be this instruction sequence:

```
0x66, 0xbb, 0x0f, 0x00, //     mov bx, 0FH
0xcd, 0x10,             //     int 10H
```

An [operand prefix 0x66](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Operand-size_and_address-size_override_prefix) in real mode decodes the instruction as the 32-bit register (in this case) and will then use 4 bytes to encode the immediate value. This of course would use the `int 10h` as part of the data for the `mov`. So what your instruction really does is:

```
0x66, 0xbb, 0x0f, 0x00, 0xcd, 0x10,  // mov ebx,0x10cd000f
```

And that would be followed by the `hlt` and `jmp` instruction as they normally appear. In code targeting 16-bit real mode (and expected to running on an 8086/8088) you don't want to use such prefixes at all. Your code should simply exclude the prefix and look like:

```
0xbb, 0x0f, 0x00,       //     mov bx, 0FH
0xcd, 0x10,             //     int 10H
```

---

You could use a disassembler that understands 16-bit instructions to disassemble the `disk.img` file. One good disassembler that can handle 16-bit code is *NDISASM* which is part of the *NASM* program (Netwide Assembler). *NASM* is available for [Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nasm/). *NDISASM* will be installed and can be run this way:

```
ndisasm -b16 disk.img
```

This will try to decode `disk.img` as a 16-bit (`-b16`) binary. You'd probably discover what the translated instructions from your bytes are and what was wrong.

You could also attempt to use the remote debugging feature in *QEMU* and use *GDB* debugger to step through your code. I don't run *QEMU* on Windows so I don't know if it is built with the remote debugging support.

---

Instead of writing your bootloader the way you are, you might consider using an assembler (like *NASM*) that can be used to generate 16-bit 8086/8088 code that is suitable for use in bootloaders. There are many questions and answers on Stackoverflow that show how *NASM* can be used to create bootloaders.

Comment: `objdump -D -Mintel,i8086 a.out` is 16-bit capable, too; for raw binaries use: `objdump -D -Mintel,i8086 -b binary -m i386 foo.bin`

Comment: @mirabilos : you are correct. The reason I didn't mention it in this particular question is that the user is on the Windows platform, and I don't know if he has a GNU Binutil tool chain on his system (ie MinGW/Cygwin/MSYS/MSYS2). I used NDISASM because I suggested _NASM_ be downloaded and the tools can run standalone without a lot of overhead.

Comment: Ah right, that’s true. In the meantime, I [extended a bit on GNU binutils’ version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34424194/2171120) elsewhere, which also contains a few pointers to `ndisasm`; the “comes with the OS” argument is moot there of course because either needs to be downloaded. (On DOS, I use `debug.com` or Borland’s Turbo Debugger for such purposes myself, the former coming with MS-DOS 3.30A.)