# Compiling assembly program to flat-form binary includes extraneous 'f' chars that don't exist in other formats

Tags: assembly, hex, nasm, elf, bin

I'm working on a program written in assembly:

```
xor eax, eax        ; make eax equal to 0
push eax            ; pushes null
push 0x68732f2f     ; pushes /sh (//)
push 0x6e69622f     ; pushes /bin
mov ebx, esp        ; passes the first argument
push eax            ; empty third argument
mov edx, esp        ; passes the third argument
push eax            ; empty second argument
mov ecx, esp        ; passes the second argument
mov al, 11          ; execve system call #11
int 0x80            ; makes  an interrupt
```

When compiled using `nasm` as a flat-form binary, I am seeing extraneous `f` characters in the hex representation of the program. I am expecting to see:

```
0000000: 31c0 5068 2f2f 7368 682f 6269 6e89 e350  1.Ph//shh/bin..P                                  
0000010: 89e2 5089 e1b0 0bcd 80                   ..P......
```

but actually see:

```
0000000: 6631 c066 5066 682f 2f73 6866 682f 6269  f1.fPfh//shfh/bi
0000010: 6e66 89e3 6650 6689 e266 5066 89e1 b00b  nf..fPf..fPf....
0000020: cd80                                     ..
```

Oddly, when I try to compile my program using `nasm` in another format such as ELF-32, I see the hex representation I am expecting (albeit lots of other hex I probably shouldn't include in my solution):

```
0000000: 7f45 4c46 0101 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
0000010: 0100 0300 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 3400 0000 0000 2800  @.......4.....(.
0000030: 0500 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000  ................
0000070: 0600 0000 0000 0000 1001 0000 1900 0000  ................
0000080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000090: 0700 0000 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000a0: 3001 0000 2100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  0...!...........
00000b0: 0100 0000 0000 0000 1100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 6001 0000 3000 0000  ........`...0...
00000d0: 0400 0000 0300 0000 0400 0000 1000 0000  ................
00000e0: 1900 0000 0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000f0: 9001 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000100: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000110: 31c0 5068 2f2f 7368 682f 6269 6e89 e350  1.Ph//shh/bin..P
0000120: 89e2 5089 e1b0 0bcd 8000 0000 0000 0000  ..P.............
0000130: 002e 7465 7874 002e 7368 7374 7274 6162  ..text..shstrtab
0000140: 002e 7379 6d74 6162 002e 7374 7274 6162  ..symtab..strtab
0000150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000170: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0400 f1ff  ................
0000180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0300 0100  ................
0000190: 0073 6865 6c6c 7370 6177 6e2e 6173 6d00  .shellspawn.asm.
```

For what I'm trying to accomplish I think I must use a flat-form binary.

**My question:** where is this `f` character coming from and what does it mean; how do i remove it?

`NASM version 2.10.09 compiled on Dec 29 2013`

`xxd V1.10 27oct98 by Juergen Weigert`

Comment: If you just want to pass pointers to NULL as the 2nd and 3rd args, why not have them both point to first `push eax` result (which is also the string terminator)?  i.e. xor-zero / push / `mov edx, esp` /  `mov ecx, esp`.  Also, [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) says you can actually pass a argv=NULL and envp=NULL (but warns that it's not portable and don't depend on it).  So you could just `xor edx,edx` / `push edx` / ... / `mov ecx,edx` / `lea eax, [edx+11]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nasm -f bin` sets the default mode to 16-bit.  In that mode, 32-bit operand-size instructions (like `xor eax,eax` or `push eax`) have to be encoded with a `0x66` operand-size prefix.  See [this table](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Operand-size_and_address-size_override_prefix) of modes vs. prefixes for operand-size and address-size.  (**`f` is `0x66` in ASCII**).  See also links to x86 manuals in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.  See also [how to disassemble flat binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424146/224132) in 16, 32, or 64-bit mode.

`-f elf` is a synonym for `-felf32`, so its targeting 32-bit mode.  `-felf64` targets 64-bit mode (where `push eax` is not encodeable).

See [section 6.1](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.1) in the NASM manual:  `BITS 32` tells the assembler to assembler for 32-bit mode, overriding the default based on the output file format.  IDK if there's a command-line option that makes flat binaries with 32-bit code.  I don't see one in the man page or --help.  If for some reason you really didn't want to change your sources, you could use `-felf` and use `ld --oformat binary` to link flat binaries.  See [How to generate plain binaries like nasm -f bin with the GNU GAS assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828631/how-to-generate-plain-binaries-like-nasm-f-bin-with-the-gnu-gas-assembler)

Ah, the docs imply that `BITS 32` is the only way:

> The most likely reason for using the BITS directive is to write 32-bit or 64-bit code in a flat binary file;

---

code review of your actual code:

If you just want to pass pointers to NULL as the 2nd and 3rd args, why not have them both point to first `push eax` result (which is also the string terminator)?  i.e. xor-zero / push / `mov edx, esp` / `mov ecx, esp`.

Also, [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) says you can actually pass a argv=NULL and envp=NULL (but warns that it's not portable and don't depend on it).  So you could just `xor edx,edx` / `push edx` / ... / `mov ecx,edx` / `lea eax, [edx+11]`.

Comment: I went with `BITS 32` and now hex is representing the way I'd like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I preface this with, I am not 100% certain of this but...

According to [This website](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x66), it is an operand size override prefix.  I'm going to guess that the assembler is being extra cautious, or perhaps it is setup for 32-bit assembler output and that this is leftover fun to try and make sure your `xor` and `mov` instructions are of the correct size.  It seems to actually not affect the runtime, if that site is correct, so perhaps just extra window dressing.

I would double check the flags passed into nasm to be sure that you aren't accidentally telling it to do move than you expect.

Or hope for a more in-depth answer from a mor recent x86 asm coder :)

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer Michael. My nasm usage is as follows: `nasm shellspawn.asm`. I have tried being more specific than this but I get the same results. I will keep researching this avenue 

Comment: It's not a question of "extra cautious".  In 32-bit code, the `0x66` operand-size means 16-bit operand size, so you have to get the mode right.  But yes, @jakenberg the default for `-fbin` is 16-bit mode.  You can use a `BITS 32` directive.  I'm not sure if there's a NASM option to set the mode to 32-bit while still making a flat binary.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I put `BITS 32` at the top of my `.asm` file and I am no longer seeing the size operand prefixes. Learned something from both of you! 